# No custom directive completion (PhpStorm 2018.3)

Tags: angularjs, webpack, phpstorm, webstorm, webpack-4

I'm struggling again with my IDE and my projects running under *Angular 1.4*, *ES 5.1*. Until now, projects where built with some gulp tasks, and AMD modules + RequireJS + bower for the Angular implementation. Everything was doing the right way (custom directives were auto completed).

I've migrated the whole thing under webpack 4, with everything ruled by some `module.exports` things and `require('lib')` (under node 8).

Now my custom directives are no longer auto completed.

- yes, AngularJS plugin is enabled in settings (bundled with the IDE)
- JS language version is 5.1
- my included libraries are `HTML` and `ziiip/node_modules`
- I've already tried to include the `angular.js` file in debug mode in those libs and it changes nothing, even after the "Invalid cache / restart" thing.

I've attached a small example of my implementation, feel free to comment but my only questions are those :

- why my `customDirective` is not recognized by the IDE
  [image: custom directive definition]
  [image: custom directive tag]
- why my all my `require` are always warning-tagged and tells me *"Element is not exported"* 
  [image: require warning]
- why `document` is tagged too
  [image: document warning]

The whole project is working when running a webpack dev server and I've attached a [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ub40jrjHlt3MC46SzB5K7TtjFmks0UFu/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get your directive recognized, you have to specify `restrict` value explicitly ([WEB-36024](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-36024)):

`module.exports = angular
        .module('app.ziiip', [])
        .directive('customDirective', function () {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                template: require('./partials/custom-directive.html')
            };
        });`

- enabling **Node.js coding assistance** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM** should fix the warning for `require`; but I'd suggest disabling **JavaScript | Node.js | Missing require() statement** and **JavaScript | General | Missing import statement** inspections as well: as you are working in CommonJS context, the IDE expects modules being exported/imported explicitly
- in `node_modules/angular/angular.js`, parameter is documented as `@param {string|DOMElement} element`, and `document` is resolved to `var document: Document` in `lib.dom.d.ts`; PhpStorm can't match types and thus shows the warning. You can suppress it by adding `// noinspection JSCheckFunctionSignatures` comment

Comment: Well, yes it fixes my bug for the custom directive exposed in my example, thx for explanation. Nonetheless it doesn't work for another directive and it has the restrict value explicited :(

Comment: But for this one I export the whole thing and I declare it only in a global index.js via a require() call 
`module.exports = { 
    myDirective: function myDirective() { 
        return {   
            restrict: 'E' , [other options] 
        }
    }
}` 
and in the index.js 
`.directive('myDirective', require('./directives/commonDirectives').myDirective)`

Comment: I'll add that for those common directives I have a `template: require(path/to/html/partial.html)`, perhaps that's why ?

Comment: this style of defining directives is not supported, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18525 to be notified on a ny progress with it